# Sample C# program to connect to Desire2Learn

Tags: desire2learn

Can someone give me a sample C# program to connect to the desire2learn APIs? I am trying to connect with the two libraries that I downloaded from Github but can not seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub authentication libraries are the place to start, along with the docs.

I would suggesting you use the [RestSharp SDK](https://github.com/Brightspace/valence-sdk-dotnet-restsharp) as the generally more robust one, but your mileage may vary. I would also suggestion you have a look at the [client-side sample](https://github.com/Brightspace/sample-valence-client-side) and [command-line utility sample](https://github.com/Brightspace/util-valence-test), also in C#.

I would suggest that you visit the [forums at D2L's developer community site](https://community.brightspace.com/devcop/support) for more timely access to their dev platform support and more direct access to the Brightspace Valence developer platform.